# Manipulating websites in VBA without any element IDs

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

Fairly new to VBA so hopefully the answer is staring me in the face!

I am trying to get info off of a website at work, the site requires you to login and then you can access the data numbers

Unfortunately, I cannot seem to find a way past the login page, mostly because I cannot find any element or ID names in the HTML code. I tried pulling by tag name but I cant seem to get it to work

Below is a sample of the HTML code without my login input, as well as one with (just using the word "LOGIN")

[image: LogIn]

When I input my login it makes the "value ="mylogin"

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: only letting me upload 1 pic.... when i input my login it makes the "value ="mylogin"

Comment: Please don't post images of code.

Comment: where is your code? And HTML should be as a code insert before potentially also adding an image.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the URL.

You can try the following methods.

---

### Ⓐ If it is the only/first input box on the page:

**1) Using a CSS selector:**

```
Set a = .document.querySelector("input[type='text']") '<==assuming is first input box on the page
```

**2) Using tagName:**

```
Set a = .document.getElementsByTagName("input")(0)
```

---

### Ⓑ If it is after the first input box on the page

You can traverse the DOM tree or refer to the appropriate index by index

**1) Using a CSS selector:**

```
Set a = .document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']") '<==assuming is first input box on the page
a.item(1).innerText '<== 1 is an example index position
'a(1).innerText  ''< or potentially this syntax
```

**2) Using tagName and index position**

```
Set a = .document.getElementsByTagName("input")(1)
```

---

**Ⓒ Optional other CSS selector:**

Just to give you some ideas about further [selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)...

You might try selector using [adjacent sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) CSS selector (`+`) and targeting the input tag after the div tag with class, `.`,  `modal-Header`:

```
.document.querySelector("div.modal-Header  + input")
```

---

**Example code usage:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    Const URL = "yourURL"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    With IE
        .Visible = False
        .navigate URL

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set a = .document.querySelector("input[type='text']") '<==assuming is first input box on the page
        'Set a = .document.getElementsByTagName("input")(0)
        a.Focus
        a.innerText = "yourLogin"
        'Other code
        '.Quit
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```